# JMockit: verify self method invocations of tested object

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have following class which I need to write unit tests to. I need to verify the invocations of own methods of `MyClass` by itself.

```
public class MyClass {
    public void init() {
    }

    public void testMethod() {
    }
}
```

I wrote following test class to test `MyClass`

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @Tested
    MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void initTest() {
//        new Expectations(myClass) {{
//        }};
        myClass.init();
        new Verifications() {{
            myClass.testMethod();
        }};
    }
}
```

As it can be seen, `init()` does not call `testMethod()`, but for my surprise, above test case succeeds.

If I partially mock `myClass` by uncommenting the empty `Expectations` block above, test fails with `Missing invocation` error, which is expected. So, it seems that I have to partially mock the tested object.

But, partially mocking a test object of a complex class throws various exceptions when testing, which is very hard to debug because breakpoints in Intellij IDEA doesn't work in this situation.

So, what may be going wrong here? Or, is it not supposed to verify the invocations of methods in the tested object itself?

Answer (score 0):

JMockit cannot verify method invocations on non-mocked class. In your example as stated, with the commented-out `Expectations`, the `myClass` object is not mocked at all, and verifications cannot actually verify that methods on it got called. It's not, strictly speaking, because you are verifying the `@Tested` object; you'd get the same issue if you created a new `List` and tried putting one of its methods in the `Verifications`.

Comment: Now, if you can provide examples of "partially mocking a test object of a complex class throw[ing] various exceptions when testing", that would be interesting to look at, because that has not been my experience.